# Windows Service using BackgroundService fails when calling HttpClient.Send

Tags: c#, windows-services, dotnet-httpclient, background-service

I have created a Windows service using the Worker template and everything works fine, until I try to send a request with HttpClient.Send(). Once I mark this out, everything works again.

It works when I start this in Visual Studio and debug it there, but if I publish it and register it as a Windows service, it fails with this exception:

---

Category: CorewsWorkerService.WindowsBackgroundService
EventId: 0

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (SECRET:443)

Exception:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (SECRET:443)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at ......

---

I don't know why it works when run manually and the connected party doesn't "properly respond after a period of time" when run in Windows services.

I have removed secrets and attached the code that is called from the WindowsBackgroundService class.

```
public class TotalArchiveService
{
    public string CallService()
    {
        //SendRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        SendRequest();
        return "OK - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    //static async Task SendRequest()
    private void SendRequest()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient {})
            {
                var endpointUrlCustomer = "https://SECRET";

                // Create HTTP request.
                var customerBuilder = new UriBuilder(new Uri($"{endpointUrlCustomer}"));
                var customerRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, customerBuilder.Uri);
                // set SOAP action
                customerRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
                // set SOAP body content 
                string xmlSOAP = GetXmlSOAP();
                customerRequest.Content = new StringContent(xmlSOAP, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                // Add signature headers to request object
                SignHttpRequestMessage(customerRequest);

                // Perform request
                var customerResponse = client.Send(customerRequest);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    //static async Task SignHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
    private void SignHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        // externalize configuration of these
        string certPath = "";
        string keyStorePassword = "";
        string keyId = "";

        certPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\cert2\cert.pfx"); // path to keystorefile
        keyStorePassword = "SECRET";
        keyId = "SECRET";

        X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, keyStorePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddHttpMessageSigning()
            .UseKeyId(keyId)
            .UseSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.CreateForSigning(cert, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
            .UseDigestAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)
            .UseUseDeprecatedAlgorithmParameter()
            .UseNonce(false)
            .UseHeaders()
            .Services;
        using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            using (var signerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestSignerFactory>())
            {
                var requestSigner = signerFactory.CreateFor(keyId);
                //await requestSigner.Sign(request);
                requestSigner.Sign(request);
            }
        }
        request.Headers.Add("Signature", request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());
        request.Headers.Authorization = null;
    }

    static string GetXmlSOAP()
    {
        string xmlSOAP = "";

        xmlSOAP = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                          xmlns:wsc=""http://edb.com/ws/WSCommon_v22"" 
                          xmlns:urn=""urn:srv.cus.corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:ws:customer:v20_1"" 
                          xmlns:urn1=""urn:srv.cus.corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:domain:customer:v20_1"" 
                          xmlns:urn2=""urn:corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:domain:common:v8"">
        <soapenv:Header>
      <wsc:AutHeader>
         <wsc:SourceApplication>SECRET</wsc:SourceApplication>
         <wsc:DestinationApplication>SECRET</wsc:DestinationApplication>
         <wsc:Function>SECRET</wsc:Function>
         <wsc:Version>20_1</wsc:Version>
         <wsc:ClientContext>
            <wsc:userid>SECRET</wsc:userid>
            <wsc:credentials/>
            <wsc:channel>BRA</wsc:channel>
            <wsc:orgid>9057</wsc:orgid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:orgunit>36000</wsc:orgunit>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:customerid>SECRET</wsc:customerid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:locale>no_NO</wsc:locale>
            <wsc:ip>127.0.0.1</wsc:ip>
         </wsc:ClientContext>
      </wsc:AutHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:customerReadRequest>
            <urn:readQualification>
                <urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
                    <urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>SECRET</urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>
                </urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
            </urn:readQualification>
        </urn:customerReadRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";


        return xmlSOAP;
    }
}
```

---

I have also tried async method, that's why there's marked out lines with async methods, "endRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();", "await requestSigner.Sign(request)" etc.

Why can't I call the web service after I register the app as a Windows service, when I active this line?

var customerResponse = client.Send(customerRequest);

When I start it in Visual Studio (result being a cmd prompt with the execution details), the request and response are captured by Fiddler as you would expect. When registering it as a service and starting that, even the request isn't captured in Fiddler. After a while, the above exception is present in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the same endpoint? Since you have one request working and one not, the easiest way to fix it is to capture them both in Fiddler or Wireshark and compare them.

Comment: It's the same solution for both "test explanations". i.e. the same code. The only difference is:

Test 1: Run the solution with the start button in Visual Studio.
Test 2: Publish the solution and register it as a Windows service - and start it.

Test 1 is captured as normal in Fiddler. Test 2 doesn't even result in a request being captured in Fiddler.

Comment: Same code, yes. But same configuration files? Possibly not.

Comment: Fair point, Stephen. I'll verify - but: The service works as intended. It runs, logs to the event viewer every 10 secs etc. It's just when I include the HttpClient.Send or HttpClient.SendAsync that it fails.

Comment: User-specific proxy, then? For context, I've used `HttpClient` in tons of Win32 services without issue. Usually the problem with services is due to either an unexpected working directory (which can cause configuration file issues) or running as a different user.

Comment: Same configuration files.

Comment: User-specific proxy is a possible issue here. Thanks :)  That said, wouldn't Fiddler at least captured the initial request out?


Can you please elaborate on working directory. This is a fairly simple prototype, single-file published to a folder on C: and registered as a sercice. Would there be other working directories to consider for such a service?


Besides that - have you used both HttpClient.Send and HttpClient.SendAsync in services?

Comment: The default working directory for services is System32, not the location of the service executable. Fiddler may not show requests if the HTTP connection failed, so you may need a lower-level monitor like Wireshark. I have used `SendAsync` in all of my services; haven't used `Send` yet. I'm 99.999% sure the problem is not with `HttpClient`.